# Python multiplication table, seperte with strings

Tags: python, string, function

I want to create a function that takes 2 parameter, and prints the multiplication table for this number in a nice format where rows are separated by lines. This is the target:
[target design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQSmN.jpg)

I have tried, but have no idea where to integrate the "--------" string. Any ideas?

```
def multi_table(x,y):
    for row in range(1, x+1):
        for col in range(1, y+1):
            num = row * col

            if num < 10: blank = '  '   
            else:
                if num < 100: blank  = ' '  
            print(blank, num, end = '')     
        print()


multi_table(4,5)
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing what you have tried already. I suggest that you show what you have tried, and what results you got when you tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the print statement between the row and column loop. You also need to ensure that you end the print statement with a new line character \n. Refer below.

```
def multi_table(x,y):
    for row in range(1, x+1):
        print("---------------------\n")
        for col in range(1, y+1):
            num = row * col

            if num < 10: blank = '  '   
            else:
                if num < 100: blank  = ' '  
            print(blank, num, end = '')     
        print()


multi_table(4,5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` is used to go to the next line, and that's where you want to add the "---------------". So change the `print()` to `print('\n------------------------\n')`. `\n` indicates to go to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

To compensate for y, you can use the following,
also, you can simplify the formatting with the format string method:

```
def multi_table(x,y):
for row in range(1, x+1):
    print('----' * y)
    for col in range(1, y+1):
        num = row * col
        print('{:4}'.format(num), end = '')
    print()
```